Seafile Swift backend - V3 token info not found
I try to configure Seafile docker to work with Swift backend.
I followed this doc, included the management of the certificate to use https.
Seafile starts well but is unusable. If I try to create a new library, it fails, if I try to upload a file, it fails.
Here is what’s in the seafile.log:
2024-07-23 08:09:20 ../common/seaf-utils.c(434): Use database Mysql
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(242): fileserver: worker_threads = 10
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(255): fileserver: backlog = 32
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(270): fileserver: fixed_block_size = 8388608
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(282): fileserver: skip_block_hash = 0
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(294): fileserver: verify_client_blocks = 0
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(309): fileserver: web_token_expire_time = 3600
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(324): fileserver: max_indexing_threads = 1
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(339): fileserver: max_index_processing_threads= 3
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(361): fileserver: cluster_shared_temp_file_mode = 600
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(428): fileserver: enable_async_indexing = 0
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(440): fileserver: async_indexing_threshold = 700
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(452): fileserver: fs_id_list_request_timeout = 300
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(465): fileserver: max_sync_file_count = 100000
2024-07-23 08:09:20 http-server.c(480): fileserver: put_head_commit_request_timeout = 10
2024-07-23 08:09:20 ../common/license.c(709): License file /opt/seafile/seafile-license.txt does not exist, allow at most 3 trial users
2024-07-23 08:09:20 filelock-mgr.c(1368): Cleaning expired file locks.
2024-07-23 08:09:20 socket file exists, delete it anyway
2024-07-23 08:09:21 ../common/swift-client.c(497): V3 token info not found.
2024-07-23 08:09:21 ../common/swift-client.c(1154): Failed to authenticate.
2024-07-23 08:09:21 ../common/swift-client.c(497): V3 token info not found.
2024-07-23 08:09:21 ../common/swift-client.c(894): [swift] Failed to authenticate.
2024-07-23 08:09:21 ../common/obj-backend-swift.c(320): Put object b29ba0551399c7041dd4fcd5fd805845f54e0517 error 32688. Response:
(null)
2024-07-23 08:09:21 repo-mgr.c(7184): Failed to add commit.
2024-07-23 08:09:21 seafile-session.c(763): Failed to create system default repo.
2024-07-23 08:09:23 start to serve on pipe client
2024-07-23 08:09:31 start to serve on pipe client
2024-07-23 08:09:31 start to serve on pipe client
2024-07-23 08:09:31 start to serve on pipe client
2024-07-23 08:09:32 start to serve on pipe client
2024-07-23 08:09:38 start to serve on pipe client
2024-07-23 08:09:40 start to serve on pipe client
2024-07-23 08:09:43 start to serve on pipe client
2024-07-23 08:09:43 start to serve on pipe client
2024-07-23 08:09:48 ../common/swift-client.c(497): V3 token info not found.
2024-07-23 08:09:48 ../common/swift-client.c(1154): Failed to authenticate.
2024-07-23 08:09:48 ../common/swift-client.c(497): V3 token info not found.
2024-07-23 08:09:48 ../common/swift-client.c(894): [swift] Failed to authenticate.
2024-07-23 08:09:48 ../common/obj-backend-swift.c(320): Put object 1001e7cf80749860760e4c39c03cc35679655b10 error 32688. Response:
(null)
2024-07-23 08:09:48 repo-mgr.c(7184): Failed to add commit.

Here is the config for your diagnostic :
[fileserver]
port = 8082

[database]
type = mysql
host = db
port = 3306
user = seafile
password = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
db_name = seafile_db
connection_charset = utf8

[notification]
enabled = false
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 8083
log_level = info
jwt_private_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[memcached]
memcached_options = --SERVER=memcached --POOL-MIN=10 --POOL-MAX=100 --RETRY-TIMEOUT=3600

[block_backend]
name = swift
tenant = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
user_name = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
password = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
container = seafile-blocks
auth_host = api.pub1.infomaniak.cloud/identity
auth_ver = v3.0
region = dc3-a
use_https = true

[commit_object_backend]
name = swift
tenant = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
user_name = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
password = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
container = seafile-commits
auth_host = api.pub1.infomaniak.cloud/identity
auth_ver = v3.0
region = dc3-a
use_https = true

[fs_object_backend]
name = swift
tenant = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
user_name = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
password = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
container = seafile-fs
auth_host = api.pub1.infomaniak.cloud/identity
auth_ver = v3.0
region = dc3-a
use_https = true

I also tried using the S3 compatible connexion but no success.
The expectation is to have a fully working seafile server using Swift/S3 storage.
